# TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url' in urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I'm getting deep into Python and was going through urllib3's docs. Tried running the code but seems like it's not working the way it's expected to.
My code is

```
import urllib3

t = urllib3.PoolManager
test = t.request('GET', 'https://shadowhosting.net/')
print(test.data)
```

And the error I get is

```
TypeError: request() missing 1 required positional argument: 'url'
```

I tried swapping place but still not working. I'm following the very beginning of the documentation(User Guide)
For reference - https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a typo forgot the parenthesis to create an object:

```
t = urllib3.PoolManager()
```

Add them and it shall work like magic:

```
import urllib3

t = urllib3.PoolManager()
test = t.request('GET', 'https://shadowhosting.net/')
print(test.data)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make `GET` request to URL then you can use `requests` module

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://shadowhosting.net/')
print(response.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs at https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html says :

```
    import urllib3

    http = urllib3.PoolManager()    //You were missing this paranthesis
    r = http.request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/robots.txt')
```

OR in case of POST request

```
r = http.request('POST','http://httpbin.org/post', fields={'hello': 'world'})
```